# Service boolean value changes unexpectedly and not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a component that has the following button in the `html`:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="changeState()">Stop/Resume Recording</button>
```

My `app.component.ts` has the following methods:

```
constructor(private fServ: FormService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.fServ.startListening(this.mandatForm.valueChanges, 450);
}

changeState() {
  console.log(this.fServ.recordingRunning); //1st log
  this.fServ.changeRecordingState();
}
```

`form.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class FormService {
formSubscription: Subscription;

lastListenValue = {};
lastListenTimestamp: number;
recordedListeningValues = [];
recordingRunning: boolean = false;

timeToNextReplay: number; //needs implementation

constructor() {}

startListening(obs: Observable<any>, debTime: number) {
  this.recordingRunning = true;
  this.recordedListeningValues = [];
  this.formSubscription = obs.debounceTime(debTime).map(data => {
    let difference = diff(this.lastListenValue, data);
    this.lastListenValue = data;
    this.lastListenTimestamp = Date.now();
    return {diff: difference, ts: this.lastListenTimestamp};
  }).subscribe(x => {
    if (this.recordingRunning) this.recordedListeningValues[x.ts] = x.diff;
  });
}

changeRecordingState() {
  console.log(this.recordingRunning); // 2nd log
  this.recordingRunning = (this.recordingRunning) ? false : true;
  console.log(this.recordingRunning); // 3rd log
}
```

Now, my problem occurs and works the following way for three clicks:

### First click

```
15:10:34.585 app.component.ts:50 true
15:10:34.585 form.service.ts:54 true
15:10:34.586 form.service.ts:56 false
```

### Second click

```
15:10:34.821 app.component.ts:50 false
15:10:34.822 form.service.ts:54 false
15:10:34.822 form.service.ts:56 true
```

### Third click

```
15:10:35.068 app.component.ts:50 false
15:10:35.068 form.service.ts:54 false
15:10:35.069 form.service.ts:56 true
```

This is utterly confusing. I don't know why the boolean value changes back to `false` once it is set to `true`. As you see, the value actually changes but then is set back to `false` again.

---

### Edit: `console.log(this.fServ)`

This is the output when I print the object right before clicking the `changeState()`:

```
app.component.ts:50 FormService {defaultTime: 250, initialFormObject: {…}, lastListenValue: {…}, recordedListeningValues: Array(0), recordingRunning: true, …}
defaultTime: 250formObservable: AnonymousSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}formSubscription: Subscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}initialFormObject: {basic: {…}, financials: {…}, location: "", visitFrequency: ""}lastListenTimestamp: nulllastListenValue: {}recordedListeningValues: Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)recordingRunning: falsereplayRunning: false__proto__: ObjectchangeRecordingState: ƒ (objectBeforeResume)pauseListening: ƒ ()resumeListening: ƒ (objectBeforeResume)startListening: ƒ (obs, debTime)startReplay: ƒ (replayValues)stopListening: ƒ ()stopReplay: ƒ ()constructor: ƒ FormService()__proto__: Object
```

[image: Better view]

I don't understand why the various values are empty. `recordedListeningValues[]` is most certainly not empty. If I return it, it has values in it. The same goes for basically all the other values. And to be clear, `recordingRunning` is `true` at that point, I have not yet changed the value of it. Can anyone explain to me why the values are stored differently?

---

### Edit 2

This is getting more and more confusing. When I subscribe to the `mandatForm.valueChanges` directly in the `app.component.ts` and keep that up. The service works as expected. I can't wrap my head around why this is happening? I do get an empty error when I try to unsubscribe from the Observable after I click the `changeState` method three times (in the case I don't subscribe to `valueChanges` in the `app.component.ts`.

### Edit 2.1

After working once, I don't get it replicated.

### Edit 3

Ok, I think I have the problem. For whatever reason, my form submit is triggered by clicking any button on it. I need to change the type to button. This was a dumb mistake.

This is/was the code in the `html` and it triggered my submit method which had some clean up logic in it:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
   <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="changeState()">Stop/Resume Recording</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="formToConsole()">Console Form</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="fServ.stopReplay()">Stop Replay</button>
```

Comment: is there any other component which inject this `FormService`? Seems like there is nothing wrong with the code you gave

Comment: No, there is not. It's utterly confusing. It's a closed circle.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the `console.log` of the actual `service` object. It shows values that are very surprising to me.

Comment: I'm seeing "Edit 3", were giving the type to the button work? `type="button"` and `type="submit"`.. were you able to solve the `recordingRunning` problem?

Comment: Yes, that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing "Edit 3", gives the type to each button, for button which should submit the form, use `type="button"`. And for the button which would submit the form, use `type="submit"`. Now the submit method will only be triggered by the button which type is `submit`.